# Integer bound with BindProperty: how to throw error instead of converting to 0?

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I generated a new razor project with `dotnet new razor`, and in `Pages/Privacy.cshtml`, I changed the page to accept a parameter:

```
@page "{foo}"
```

and in `Pages/Privacy.cshtml.cs`, I added the following the grab and print the parameter:

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public int Foo { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{this.Foo}");
}
```

This works as expected when I do `curl https://localhost:6789/privacy/123`. However, when I pass a non-integer like `curl https://localhost:6789/privacy/notandinteger`, it prints 0. I feel this is dangerous and incorrect because I can't tell if the client actually wants `0` or gave a bad input.

Is there a way to detect such bad inputs and return a 4xx error?

Comment: You can try using [PageModel.ModelState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagemodel.modelstate?view=aspnetcore-7.0), it has a  `bool IsValid` property and you can also look at the validation result for each property for which Binding took place.

Comment: You could set the property type to be nullable (int?). I imagine it will set the value to null if it's not a number instead of defaulting to 0 as it does.

Answer (score 1):

You can [use a constraint](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#adding-constraints) to specify that the value must be an integer:

```
@page "{foo:int}"
```

If anyone tries to reach the page without passing an int, the route will not be satisfied and this page will not be served. If no other page satisfies the route, the framework returns a 404.